# Best way to handle often used sql-informations in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

What is the best and most resource-efficient way to handle often needed SQL informations, in my example "real username"?

My Model:

```
public function pageModification()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PageModification','page_id','id');
}

public static function getPages($id)
{
    return Page::with('pageModification')->where('page_id', '=', $id)->get();
}
```

My Result looks something like this:

```
array(36) [
'id' => integer 64
'title' => string (11) "lorem ipsum"
'content' => string (11) "lorem ipsum"        
'post_page_modification' => array(11) [
    array(3) [
        'id' => integer 34
        'post_id' => integer 64
        'user_id' => integer 12

        .....
    ]
```

What is now the best way to get the real username (first name, last name) from my usertable by means of the user_id? 
It can occur up to 100 user_id's by one call, and mostly/often it's the same user_id.
Do I have 100 times call a function like "getUserNameById()" to get the real names?

Comment: use a cache? `if(query parameters in cache) { return cached value } else { run query; put results in cache; return results }`

Answer (score 0):

I see you are already using eager loading, now be prepared to have your mind blown.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

"
You may even eager load nested relationships:

`$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();`

In the example above, the author relationship will be eager loaded, and the author's contacts relation will also be loaded.
"

So just make sure you have your relations set up correctly and then you can just eager load that too.

`return Page::with('pageModification.user')->where('page_id', '=', $id)->get();`